# How can I calculate the number of lines changed between local files and remote gitlab versions

Tags: java, git, jenkins, github, gitlab

As part of my code churn reporting, I am trying to create a code churn report which captures the number of lines changed between local versions of some files and the associated remote files.

Assume I have the following project structure:

```
C:\dev_ws\helloApp\services\ServiceA
C:\dev_ws\helloApp\services\ServiceB
C:\dev_ws\helloApp\services\ServiceC
```

The services A,B,C folders have local versions of `git` files.
The idea is to create a report capturing the total number of lines changed across all the files contained in services A,B,C recursively.

The `Git` version will always contain the delta i.e. the `Gitlab` version is been worked on by developers.

I am doing this on `Windows 7` machine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `git diff --numstat <commit-is> <commit-ish>` to get this diff. 
The `--numstat` gives a script parsable output. You can also use the `--stat` to get a human readable output.

Here's an example

> $ git diff --numstat e900ddd5fd6fcd477d0de0596630a573aa7d365a
>   c1a69ab0cef554fd1077b39db3aeddcddabc9534
>
> 2       1       fileA
>
> $ git diff --stat e900ddd5fd6fcd477d0de0596630a573aa7d365a c1a69ab0cef554fd1077b39db3aeddcddabc9534
>
> fileA | 3 ++-  1 file
>   changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

Comment: Thanks MandarT and Yogesh_D. I ran the following: C:\[git-repo-directory i.e. C:\myapp]>git diff --shortstat C:\myapp\services origin/master:C:\myapp\services and it gave me : 8 files changed, 690 insertions(+), 579 deletions(-). Can I invoke that git command from a java class, and extract the total line changed?  Future task will be automating to run from Jenkins. But, immediate task is invoking the git diff --numstat from Java or is windows batch the only option? Thanks for your assistance all.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script which will iterate through all the changed files.

To get the number of lines changed from that you can use below command:

git diff **--shortstat** <<<**local file path**>>> <<<**origin/branchname: file path**>>>

Above command will provide output as:
**1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)**

Hope this is what you are expecting.